# APNS: Does not work on Windows Server

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to setup apple push notification using C#. I am able to test and get everything working on my laptop (dev machine). When I move the published code to the windows server; no errors were thrown and no notification was sent out.  I even set my application pool to local server.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up creating a work around for this. I never got it to work from an asp.net page.  What I did is have my asp.net page insert a record in a queue table. I then also created an console app that is call every 5 seconds to look in the queue table and perform a push notification.

Comment: Would you be willing to share how you are doing it?  I am also wanting to do the same thing.  I think the route you took (polling a table for notifications) is the best fit for my needs too.  If you are able to help me out, please email me at eljaywilson_at_gmail_dot_com.  Thanks!

Comment: I just put the code inside a console app and not in a asp.net code behide.  I schedule a job that executes the console app every n-minutes.. the console app querys a table in the db that looks for notification to be sent out. that is it.

Comment: I mean I need help with the whole server setup (installing the certs, creating the connection to apns, etc) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make certificate for this production machine as well. I believe you may have missed that step and did the same for your laptop.

Consider this [link](http://x-cake.ning.com/profiles/blogs/setting-up-a-push-notification) to review your steps one more time.

Thanks

Comment: The Notification.Test Program works on the server. It is the IIS that is not working. I am at a point that I think I need to execute WinHttpCertCfg and grant some permissions. But I am getting Unable to find context for the certificate error

Comment: I was able to grant permissions to the certificate for ASPNET, Network Service and Authenticated User; But it is still not sending out the notification.  I have the jdsoft.notification.test program on the same server and that test program is sending out the notification. My IIS (Website) is not sending it out. and not errors are thrown.